# To group and print results of results of student based on the result using collections

Tags: java

My question is : I have arraylist of Student objects which have values  like  name(String), age(int), MarksScoredInPercentage(double) and result(String). Now I created multiple objects of students where some student result are Fail, Some are FC(First Class), and Some are SC(Second Class).

Now I have to iterate the the array list and publish the result as output where students are grouped based on their result and displayed.

```
 Output should be like
***** List of First class Student*******
Name 1:
Name 2:
****** List of Second Class Student*****
Name1:
Name 2:
****** List Of Fail Student ******
Name1:
Name 2
```

Comment: please update your code.

Comment: while iterating arraylist check result value and again create three list to store first class student , Second Class student and fail student.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the Student class as follows:

```
public class Student {
    private String result;


    /**
     * Getter for property 'result'.
     *
     * @return Value for property 'result'.
     */
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property 'result'.
     *
     * @param result Value to set for property 'result'.
     */
    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

Grouping using streams:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Set<Student>> groupedStudents = students.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Student::getResult, Collectors.toSet()
                )
        );
```

This would give the students for each result.